# Unable to carry our a unit test in NetBeans

Tags: java, unit-testing, netbeans, zk

I've been trying to carry out a simple unit test on a java class. The problem is that it is not a mere java class running by itself, but part of a large project that has to be deployed before running. The class itself is called from a .zul file (ZK framework) and a database connection is required.

Whenever I run the unit test I get something like this:

> [EL Severe]: ejb: 2018-12-19 15:48:27.11--ServerSession(254896875)--Exception [EclipseLink-7060] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.2.v20140319-9ad6abd): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.ValidationException
>   Exception Description: Cannot acquire data source [mydb]
>   Internal Exception: javax.naming.NameNotFoundException; remaining name 'mydb'

The error message arises when the system calls a function that fetches data from the db. In particular, it arises because of this line:

```
    period.setDataModel(findAllPeriod());
```

"period" is a component of the .zul file, while findAllPeriod() is the function that fetches the data.

According to most related topics I've read so far, it could be related to the persistence.xml. There are two such xmls in the project. The first contains the line

```
*<jta-data-source>mydb</jta-data-source>*
```

and it is the only file that even mentions mydb explicitly. The other persistence.xml contains the line above as a comment, as well as the following:

```
  *<property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="${jdbc.url}"/>
  <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="${jdbc.user}"/>
  <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="${jdbc.driver}"/>
  <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="${jdbc.password}"/>*
```

Could something be wrong with the persistence.xml? Or it's the ZK framework somehow responsible for the problem?

I use NetBeans 8.2, Glassfish 4.1, and ZK.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Not ZK related. Does your server have a jndi named mydb?

Comment: No, but when I deploy the application (at least without the test file) it runs normally and fetches data from the db, so I think it  is properly configured. Yet that is just my opinion

Comment: The file is located under test sources? Otherwise search me up on Linkedin and I'll ask you more details there in order to help you

Comment: Yeah, it is under the test sources, as is supposed to be (I apologize for the delay)